# How to profile point cloud

Tags: matlab, profile

I have a point cloud with 3D coordinates. how can I using `improfile` build a profile for my data?
I mean I think `improfile` is for an image only. is this true or for a point cloud is too?

Comment: What do you want to achieve, specifically, not in terms of `improfile`?

Comment: You mean a profile of the point density? Then the first step would be to estimate this density, e.g. as a three-dimensional histogram, which is a 3d-array. However, as far as I can see, `improfile` operates only on images, i.e. 2d-arrays.